# Android - How to add new version of Google map api to fragment instead of Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

The official document of Google map API is placed the code inside the Activity.

But when I googled for the solution for fragment, I found some solutions use getMap() method, but this method has been deprecated.

So what I want to ask is : How to do that in new version of Google Map API ?

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `getMapAsync` method instead of `getMap`:

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="mypackage.MyMapFragment" />
```

**mypackage.MyMapFragment.java**

```
public class MyMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMapAsync(this);;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(40, -4)).title("My Marker"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(40, -4), 13));
    }
}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the [Google Play service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#specify_the_google_play_services_version_number) version number by adding the following declaration within the `<application>` element of `AndroidManifest.xml`. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with.

The `getMap()` method is already deprecated. You should use [`public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)) method. It sets a callback object which will be triggered when the [`GoogleMap`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap) instance is ready to be used.